# Any example of (roughly) independent variables that are dependent at extreme values?

Tags: correlation, extreme-value

I am looking for an example of 2 random variables $X$, $Y$ such that

$$\newcommand{\cor}{{\rm cor}}|\cor(X,Y)| \approx 0 $$

but when consider the tail part of the distributions, they are highly correlated. (I try to avoid 'correlated' / 'correlation' for the tail because it might not be linear).

Probably use this:

$$|\cor(X', Y')| \gg 0$$

where $X'$ is conditional on $X > 90\%$ of $X$'s population, and $Y'$ is defined in the same sense.

Comment: Independent variables that are dependent? My brain just exploded. You can't ask this sort of question on Monday morning

Comment: Given the upvoted answer, this Q does seem answerable.

Comment: I think Aksakal's point is that the title is misleading.

Comment: The title is somewhat misleading but I've answered the question as elaborated in the post.

Comment: The question remains unclear. I suppose it could be rephrased using local dependence / global near-independence or something like that.

Comment: To help this make sense to people, consider how much you care about gun issues and how much you like/hate the NRA. The correlation will probably be near zero. People who care the most about gun issues can either love or hate the NRA. But they will be very dependent. People who care the most about gun issues will almost never be in the middle of the pro-NRA/anti-NRA spectrum. People at the very top or bottom end of the pro-NRA/anti-NRA spectrum will tend to care more about gun issues than people in the middle.

Comment: I'm sorry for stating the unclear question. I just want to visualize how it works for some independent distributions having some kinda of extreme dependence (not necessarily correlation).

Comment: There are a host of copulas with weak overall dependence but strong tail dependence; the exact overall correlation would be affected by what the distribution of the marginals was.

Comment: @kmz - I think you need to realize independence has a very specific and strong meaning in probability and statistics.

Comment: Practical example: might something like home-insurance and auto-insurance claims look like this? They're basically driven by different, independent effects... except when a hurricane hits and everything is !@#$!@#$ed?

Comment: Are you talking about correlation or independence? There is such a thing as "almost" independent (see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/67328/10636)) which is an interesting concept, but you seem to have confused independence with correlation, which is... less interesting. :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's an example where $X$ and $Y$ even have normal marginals.

Let:

$$X \sim N(0,1)$$

Conditional on $X$, let $Y = X$ if $|X| > \phi$, or $Y = -X$ otherwise, for some constant $\phi$.

You can show that, independently of $\phi$, marginally we have:

$$Y \sim N(0,1)$$

There is a value of $\phi$ such that $\text{cor}(X,Y) = 0$. If $\phi = 1.54$ then $\text{cor}(X,Y)\approx 0$.

However, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, and extreme values of both are perfectly dependent. See simulation in R below, and the plot that follows.

```
Nsim <- 10000
set.seed(123)

x <- rnorm(Nsim)
y <- ifelse(abs(x)>1.54,x,-x)

print(cor(x,y)) # 0.00284 \approx 0

plot(x,y)

extreme.x <- which(abs(x)>qnorm(0.95))
extreme.y <- which(abs(y)>qnorm(0.95))
extreme.both <- intersect(extreme.x,extreme.y)

print(cor(x[extreme.both],y[extreme.both])) # Exactly 1
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) If you want the distribution to not just be uncorrelated, but also not very dependent, you can do a modification of this that replaces the hard threshold swap with a fuzzy one. That's harder to get the math to line up, but it's doable.

Comment: Thank you Chris Haug! Your idea helps me visualize what I'm doing.